# Protect Java Spring Web App with DMZ

Tags: java, security, apache, tomcat

Currently, I am designing my Java Spring + Web application deployment and planning to protect the internal resources with a DMZ.  In many articles / tutorials I read, all the components (web/business/dao) are placed to a webapp file.   I am planning to use Apache Tomcat as the app server.  Then, is it the only solution to place all of them into a webapp file for Apache Tomcat?  Is it possible to separate the business components to a server in the internal network, while leaving the web components in DMZ?  Any suggestion and recommendations are welcomed.  Tks in advance!

Tks & B.Regards
Tommy Chan

Comment: Everything is possible... it depends on your security requirements. The 'standard' setup is having a web server (HTTP) in DMZ, application server (Tomcat) in internal network and database as well. I've seen setups in which the application server was placed in its own zone again... you should discuss with your network infrastructure team.